# Why is there a gap between print statements?

Tags: c, string, parsing

I'm trying to parse through input and store them in an array of strings. So if the user inputs {"hello world | foo bar"} I'd parse based on the space and if there's a | or eof I store a null. Once I finished parsing and want to check the stored tokens using:

```
while(i < j) {
    printf("%s\n", args[i]);
    i++;
}
```

The output is something like

```
hello
world
(null)
foo

bar
(null)
```

So what's with this gap?

Comment: Can we see the code that populates args?

Comment: I messed up the while loop when storing the tokens. It's working perfectly now

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make sure you are really measuring your output and not your combined input and output.  The easiest way to do this is to redirect your output to a file.  Assuming your program name is "a.out"

```
 a.out > output.txt
```

or the equivalent is going to give you a file with only the output in it.  If it is exactly the same as what you posted, then you know that it is not your console / terminal trying to draw the carriage returns and line feeds that you are typing, it is the console trying to draw the carriage returns and line feeds the program is printing out.

Once you have a good grip on which input / output stream is printing what, then remember that if `args[i]` contains a `\n` newline, it's going to print it out just like if it contained the word `hello`.  You might have to hunt down the source of the newline, and correct it there.  An easy way is to suppress the printing if `args[i]` matches undesirable text; however, such a technique is generally to be avoided in non-toy programs as it eventually allows bad data in the variables, and that means it becomes more difficult (if not impossible) to maintain over time.